# GTK# using DrawingArea

Tags: c#, linux, draw, cairo, gtk#

I want to write a Snake game using GTK# but for several days I can't figure out the way dealing with `DrawingArea`. In all the examples that I've found, there's subscribtion to the `drawingArea.ExposeEvent` event, a method like:

```cs
void OnDrawingAreaExposed (object source, ExposeEventArgs args)
{   
    DrawingArea darea = (DrawingArea) source;
    Cairo.Context ctx = Gdk.CairoHelper.Create (darea.GdkWindow);

    // drawing here ...

    ((IDisposable) ctx.Target).Dispose();
    ((IDisposable) ctx).Dispose();
}
```

But I have neither `.ExposeEvent` event available on the `DrawingArea` object, nor the `ExposeEventArgs` data type.
I don't even know what it's about. I would like to deal with rendering, perhaps even in other way, for example to make a bitmap image then assign it to something like `PictureBox` from WinForms.

Also, I have to draw at set intervals, which means I need other GTK# methods too.

I used `darea.GdkWindow` to create the `Cairo.Context`, but it is maked as "deprecated". I've tried just creating a Cairo.Context and then drawing with the `darea.Draw(cc)` method, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: It's better to include to the post the .NET and the library version are you using.

Comment: @aepot, I write on dotnet6. The GTK version is apparently 3.24
(as written in the Csproj file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `DrawingArea.Drawn` event.

```
var drawing = new DrawingArea();
drawing.Drawn += (s, e) =>
{
    var cr = e.Cr;
    cr.Rectangle(100, 100, 100, 100);
    cr.SetSourceRGB(255, 0, 0);
    cr.Fill();
};
```

Reference:  https://github.com/GtkSharp/GtkSharp/blob/develop/Source/Samples/Sections/Widgets/DrawingAreaSection.cs